# Angular2 sibling component communication, component not subscribing to service

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm attempting to use a service to communicate between sibling components in the same page, but the listening component is not firing on the change of the subscribed object:

#### Service

```
import {Injectable}     from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {ReportTable} from '../classes/report.table.class';
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ReportService {

    private payload = new Subject<string>();

    // Observable string streams
    payload$ = this.payload.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    public communicate(payload: string) {
        console.log('called2');
        this.payload.next(payload);
    }
}
```

#### Broadcasting Component

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {FilterComponent} from '../reports/filter.component';
import {ReportService} from '../../services/report.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'filteroptions',
    templateUrl: '/Reports/filteroptions.template.html',
    providers: [ReportService]
})

export class FilterOptionsComponent {
    displayId: string;

    constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {             
    }


    passDisplayId(displayId: string) {
        console.log('called1');
        this.reportService.communicate(displayId);
    }
}
```

#### Listening Component

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from 'angular2/core';
import {ReportService} from '../../services/riskreport.service';
import {ReportTable} from  '../../classes/riskreport.table.class';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS}    from 'angular2/http';
import {DataTable} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Column} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Subscription}   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    selector: 'report-table',
    templateUrl: '/Reports/riskreport.table.template.html',
    providers: [ReportService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [DataTable, Column]
})

export class ReportTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    public subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {
        this.subscription = this.reportService.payload$.subscribe(m => console.log('called3'));
    }

    ngOnInit() {}            

    // Prevent memory leak
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I can see in my console that `called1` and `called2` are logged, but `called3` is not. Why isn't my second component listening/subscribing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two instances of your service:

One here:

```
providers: [ReportService]
```

And one here:

```
providers: [ReportService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
```

Each time you add it to a providers array, you are creating a new instance. You want to include it in the providers array of a common parent element. This will give them both access to the same instance of the service.

If you have more than one element using `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, you should move that up to a common parent element as well.

Comment: Ahh, perfect. So the child components inherit provider instances from their parent. Is this available only to immediate children or to grandchildren, and so on?

Comment: Grandchildren too. I generally put it on my main app component, so it's available to everything.

Comment: @EchoLogic Can you please update the working code in your question. I am also facing the same problem, I have invested hours in this. but nothing is happenings.